# Помогите решить задачу c# Определить сколько процентов

Tags: c#

Определить сколько процентов от всего количества элементов произвольного массива целых чисел составляют элементы, содержащие нечётные значения

Comment: циклом пройтись по массиву, посчитать количество нечетных элементов и разделить на длину массива (общее количество элементов)

Answer (score 8):

Например, можно реализовать это так:

```
public static void countRandPercents(int length, int from, int to)
{
      int[] randNums = new int[length];
      Random rnd = new Random();
      int countOdd = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<randNums.Length;i++){
            randNums[i] = rnd.Next(from, to+1);
            if(randNums[i]%2!=0) countOdd++;  
      }
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", randNums));
      double percents = (double)countOdd/randNums.Length;
      Console.WriteLine("Нечетных: "+percents*100+"%");
}
```

Тогда, при вызове `countRandPercents(5,1,100);` вывод:

```
22 98 30 99 42
Нечетных: 20%
```

Comment: Можно еще так `$"Нечетных: {percents:P0}"` :) Еще вы заранее объявляете `percents`, при этом не используете переменную в цикле. Это сбивает с толку. А еще токой фокус попробуйте после цикла `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", randNums))`, а то вывод даже 30 чисел будет слегка неудобным.

Comment: Согласна, вывод неудобный, но по условию задачи он не требуется, сделала чисто для примера и наглядности. Вы абсолютно правы! :)